# How to achieve left join on entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, left-join

I have an issue returning records from Contacts regardless if the joining entities match. I am trying to achieve the equivalent of a left join.

The problem is the query only works if contacts contains a relationship in all the related tables. I want to return contact records regardless of a join record in the related entities.

```
var SubQuery = from Contacts in db.Contacts
               join ContactAddictions in db.ContactAddictions.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    on Contacts.ID equals ContactAddictions.ContactID
               join ContactTreatmentPreferences in db.ContactTreatmentPreferences.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    on Contacts.ID equals ContactTreatmentPreferences.ContactID
               join TreatmentHistories in db.TreatmentHistories.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    on Contacts.ID equals TreatmentHistories.ContactID
               where
                    Contacts.ID == ID
               select Contacts;

var Query = SubQuery.Include("ContactAddictions")
    .Include("ContactTreatmentPreferences")
    .Include("ContactAddictions.Tag")
    .Include("ContactTreatmentPreferences.Tag")
    .Include("TreatmentHistories")
    .Include("TreatmentHistories.TreatmentCenter")
    .Include("ContactDispositionType")
    .Include("State");
```

Comment: you mean Left OUTER Join like in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx ?

Comment: You didn't state what your problem was...

Comment: The problem is the query only works if contacts contains a relationship in all the related tables. I want to return contact records regardless of a join record in the related entities.

Comment: So you do not want a join, because you do not care about the join. You just select all tables and group by ContactID

Comment: @Serv - I think I know what you mean. I'll try that out thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Just select your 4 tables, remove the joins and and group/order your result by your contact ID. If it still does not fit: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg Look here what you want

Comment: I got it working but did not need the group by. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Serv for suggesting the right path!

This is the final query than handles my requirement.

```
      var SubQuery = from Contacts in db.Contacts
                       from ContactAddictions in db.ContactAddictions.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       from ContactTreatmentPreferences in db.ContactTreatmentPreferences.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       from TreatmentHistories in db.TreatmentHistories.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       orderby
                           Contacts.LastName, Contacts.FirstName
                       where
                            Contacts.ID == ID
                       select Contacts;

        var Query = SubQuery.Include("ContactAddictions")
            .Include("ContactTreatmentPreferences")
            .Include("ContactAddictions.Tag")
            .Include("ContactTreatmentPreferences.Tag")
            .Include("TreatmentHistories")
            .Include("TreatmentHistories.TreatmentCenter")
            .Include("ContactDispositionType")
            .Include("State");
        return Query.FirstOrDefault();
```